# Is it possible to hide a web based game jQuery code from the user?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know some of you just feel it is as a completely wrong question but I have a few requirements of such kind that's why I am asking this question. I understand that javascript is downloaded by the browser on client side so it's very difficult to hide that.

So now i have a game code completely written in jquery and i want that the user is not able to see the complete code because:

1. The owner of the games doesn't want to show the game code to the user.
2. If a clever user reads the code carefully then he/she might be able to solve the puzzle(it's a puzzle game).

So, is it good enough to use google closure compiler or yui compressor to make the code unreadable & secure for the above requirements?

If you think that it's not possible to do this in the situation then please suggest me any other way of doing this. Do I need to completely rewrite the game code into a server side language then convert it to js using some tool?

Comment: @Peeyush Depending on the size of the script with some tools, the smart user will get the needed part of the code in less than 10 minutes. JavaScript still don't have this kind of security. Of course you can minify and pack the code, but this will only slow the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is a client language, for that, you will always need to show the code to the user.

**What you can do is** compress and minified...

same thing as all Javascript Frameworks outthere, check [this original version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js) and compare with the [minified and compressed version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js)

Comment: so i think google closure compiler is good enough for it.is it so?

Comment: best one in the market is [Yahoo Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), but you can use any other...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect solution in any way, just one option: you may fetch the actual javascript code from the server via AJAX requests and make them runnable, eg. by eval()-ing them.

This will still not hide the code completely, but this makes the source invisible in the source code itself.

By the way obfuscating the source is an other practice to make the code unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not having the entire game in js (i.e. download to the client).  No matter what you do to obfuscate the code someone will figure it out and post about it.  Put all the game logic and puzzles on the server side with rpc calls of some type.  This can be something simple as a php script that you send ajax messages to that checks if a solution increment is correct.  The php script would then look up the answer and return a response.  Of course it doesn't have to be php, use whatever server side tech you are knowledgeable in.